# Sonar javascript plugin incosistency in highlighting

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonar-runner

In our company we are running Sonar with javascript plugin enabled.
The plugin seems to break sometimes on highlighting the code. The sonar runner has no trouble but the background tasks in the server are sometimes running for 30 minutes because of several exceptions.

We are running on SonarQube 5.3 with the javascript plugin latest version at the moment 2.11 enabled.

The exceptions we are having are as follows:

```
    2016.03.09 13:32:02 WARN  [o.s.s.c.s.HighlightingLineReader] Inconsistency detected in Highlighting data. Highlighting will be ignored for file '[filename]'
org.sonar.server.computation.source.RangeOffsetConverter$RangeOffsetConverterException: End offset 25 is defined outside the length (24) of the line 2
    at org.sonar.server.computation.source.RangeOffsetConverter.checkExpression(RangeOffsetConverter.java:67) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.source.RangeOffsetConverter.validateEndOffsetNotGreaterThanLineLength(RangeOffsetConverter.java:61) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.source.RangeOffsetConverter.offsetToString(RangeOffsetConverter.java:37) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.source.HighlightingLineReader.processHighlighting(HighlightingLineReader.java:105) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.source.HighlightingLineReader.processHighlightings(HighlightingLineReader.java:92) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.source.HighlightingLineReader.read(HighlightingLineReader.java:79) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.source.ComputeFileSourceData.read(ComputeFileSourceData.java:62) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.source.ComputeFileSourceData.compute(ComputeFileSourceData.java:49) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistFileSourcesStep$FileSourceVisitor.visitFile(PersistFileSourcesStep.java:132) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitNode(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:80) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitImpl(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:52) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visit(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:40) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitChildren(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:99) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitImpl(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:55) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visit(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:40) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitChildren(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:99) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitImpl(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:55) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visit(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:40) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitChildren(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:99) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitImpl(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:55) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visit(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:40) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistFileSourcesStep.execute(PersistFileSourcesStep.java:92) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:39) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:72) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:81) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:56) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_65]
```

After some analysis of the problem we found that there was an issue with BOM characters but it was solved in a previous release. It might be though that the files it crashes on are files with BOM characters and we thus also doubt if the fix for the BOM files worked. The lines the highlighter crashes on is random and not always the first line.

I have looked through the code of the javascript plugin and I think that there is a mistake when calculating the offsets.

Any help is much appreciated!

UPDATE:

Here are the first four lines of the file it is trying to highlight (it breaks on the second):

```
require('./sass/site.scss');
require('./sass/ns-popover.scss');

window.jQuery = window.$ = require('./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js');
```

Comment: As this is a bug and not a question, please use the [sonarqube google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube). Moreover, it would be easier to understand the problem if you could share the content of the file mentioned in the stacktrace, at least the lines on which the problem appears.

Comment: Hi @Pierre-Yves-SonarSourceTeam thanks for your response! I added the lines of code that break the highlighter. I heard from other people to use stackoverflow for the bugs so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Can you share the file itself? This issue may be linked to the encoding.

Comment: Hi @Pierre-Yves-SonarSourceTeam it took some time as I had to discuss which file we could share. I have added an issue on the google groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/2pJz-sNPc-k and attached the file there.